# How eigendecomposition helps to solve $\operatorname*{argmax}_d\operatorname{Tr}(d^TX^TXd)$ in PCA

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I cannot understand the highlighted statement in the book Deep Learning.
Can someone explain why we can solve this optimization problem using eigendecomposition?

Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The key is that $X^TX$ is a symmetric matrix, and $d^T(X^TX)d$ is the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient); see also "Rayleigh's theorem".  For a reference on all that, I'd recommend either Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* or Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*.